# Getting video source/location from a webpage

Tags: firefox, video, download

There is a video embedded in a web page that I am trying to download and I need it's location. Using FireFox Dev Tools > Network, I can see requests for lots of m2ts of the video but those are just small video segments of a few seconds.

I can download those/open those in a media player like VLC but again they are just segments.

Is there a way to 'sniff' or get the actual video location embedded in a web page with other tools or methods?

Comment: Try an extension called Download Helper - works for me just about everywhere except youtube

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tool to grab the videos on a page, etc. then you may want to take a look at the Download Helper extension for Firefox.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/

Parses many pages/sites for embedded video, gives you a quick download option, or if you install some extra programs will allow download and conversion - ie, strip audio out of a movie file and save as an mp3 file.